# Does hive table name support wildcard?

Tags: hive

there are some tables in hive, with the same pattern like this: `product_info_{xxx}_manual`
I want to get min and max datetime of these tables, now I use sql like below

```
select 'foo', min(dt), max(dt) from product_info_foo_manual
union
select 'bar', min(dt), max(dt) from product_info_bar_manual
union
select 'foobar', min(dt), max(dt) from product_info_foobar_manual
...
```

Does hive support `wildcard` could implement above requirement more easyly, e.g

```
select substring(table_name, x,y),min(dt), max(dt) from product_info_*_manual
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, wildcards in table name is not supported in SELECT statement. Wildcard is supported in the `show tables`, so you can execute SHOW TABLES, get result in a shell and loop through it and parametrize your select query.

For example like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for table_name in $(hive -e "use mydb; show tables 'product_info_*_manual';") 
do
   hive -S -e "use $db; select substring(${table_name}, x,y),min(dt), max(dt) from ${table_name};"
done
```